# Is it possible to combine beforeEach & afterEach Cypress's hooks into a custom command?

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, hook, cypress

Is it possible to combine a custom command which gets trigger in both `beforeEach` & `afterEach` hooks? I'm currently using the `cypress-localstorage-commands` [plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-localstorage-commands) like so:

```js
beforeEach(() => {
  cy.restoreLocalStorage();
});

afterEach(() => {
  cy.saveLocalStorage();
});
```

Is there a way to abstract this into a `custom command` so I don't need to add these `hooks` or reuse this code in each `spec` file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not an expert in Cypress specifically, but all testing libraries have to play by the rules of Javascript: their "special functions" (like `beforeEach`/`afterEach`) are still just Javascript functions.

Thus, I *believe* that if you want to make a function that adds both a `beforeEach` and `afterEach`, it should be as simple as:

```
const addBoth = () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      cy.restoreLocalStorage();
    });

    afterEach(() => {
      cy.saveLocalStorage();
    });
};
```

and then you just call:

```
addBoth();
```

everywhere that you want to add both.  And this should be true of **any** JS library (testing or otherwise), unless it is doing something really clever involving function scopes behind the scenes (eg. React hooks).